# отображение данных из БД через RestAPI

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте! У меня имеется API реализующий добавление объектов через запрос по адресу `127.0.0.1:8000/my_api/objects/`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать отображение объектов из БД при запросе на адрес `127.0.0.1:8000/my_api/objects/X`. Где `X` - это `id` объекта из БД.

Сериализатор выглядит примерно так:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    type = ChoiceField(Device.TYPE_CHOICES, required=True)
    status = BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = DateTimeField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ('id', 'type', 'name', 'status', 'created_at')
```

View выглядит примерно так:

```
class DevicesViewSet(GenericAPIView, ViewSetMixin, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, CreateModelMixin):
    http_method_names = ['post']
    queryset = Object.objects
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

Но фактически этот код используется для реализации функционала по добавлению в БД новых записей

Comment: Это можно сделать разными способами, добавьте код view в вопрос

Comment: Добавил код, о котором Вы просили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените все миксины во вью одним из вьюсетов `ReadOnlyModelViewset`, если вам нужно только отображение объектов по GET запросу или `ModelViewSet`, если вам нужно еще и изменять объекты. По сути это классы аггрегаторы которые собраны из этих миксинов, которые направляют соответствующие запросы на нужные методы с помощью роутеров.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class DevicesViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Object.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

в `urls.py` укажите роутер для вьюсета:

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('objects', DevicesViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Этого хватит чтобы постороить апи для модели `Object`.

GET `/objects/` - список объектов .

GET `/objects/:id` - один объект

Answer (score 0):

Вот это должно сработать:
**views.py**

```
class ObjectDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Object.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^my_api/objects/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ObjectDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='object-detail'),
    ...
]
```

Comment: при обработке роута падает с ошибкой: TypeError: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`